# How to change the color of a check box in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import { Checkbox } from 'antd' 

<Checkbox style={{ color: 'red', backgroundColor: 'black' }}>Dr John</Checkbox>
```

How do I change the color of the check box, not the label 'Dr John'? The style above only changes the styles of the label, not the check box.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use simple css

```css
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I want to apply the css dynamically(different colors for a range of check boxes based on some given input).

Comment: Here is a codeSandBox [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n59zxxxyol) I did using styled-components.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: any idea how to implement this on table's selection checkbox ?

Comment: @HilalArsa Can you share an example?

Comment: Its been a while, but do you by any chance know how to reset a color of a checkbox when it is hovered? I have changed the color of a checked item successfully, but it is still blue when hovered

Answer (score 3):

I was able to dynamically change the checkbox's color using @humanbean's and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503150/adding-style-attributes-to-a-css-class-dynamically-in-react-app) answer.

Checkboxes.js

```
<Checkbox
    value={key}
    key={index}
    style={{
        "--background-color": boxColors[index],
        "--border-color": boxColors[index],
    }}>
    Title
</Checkbox>
```

CSS

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    border-color: var(--border-color);
}
```

Using var() function in css and providing the color in inline style of the component.

Answer (score 3):

```
const CustomCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  ${props =>
    props.backgroundColor &&
    css`
      & .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
        background-color: ${props.backgroundColor};
        border-color: ${props.backgroundColor};
      }
    `}
`;
```

with [styled-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) package you can do something like this.

`<CustomCheckbox backgroundColor='green' />`

Answer (score 2):

Override the default antd checkbox classes in your css and provide the necessary attributes to custom it.

For example,

**index.css**

```
.ant-checkbox .ant-checkbox-inner {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}

.ant-checkbox-disabled .ant-checkbox-inner {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}

.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: red;
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Checkbox } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  onChange(e) {
    console.log(`checked = ${e.target.checked}`);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox onChange={this.onChange} disabled={true}>Checkbox</Checkbox>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    .checkbox { 
        .ant-checkbox .ant-checkbox-inner {
            border-color: red;                 // for mouse focus color
        }
      .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
            background-color: green;         // selected color
            border-color: green;
        }
    }




.checkbox {     
  .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
        background-color: green80;
        border-color: green80;
    }   
    .ant-checkbox-wrapper:hover .ant-checkbox-inner,
  .ant-checkbox:hover .ant-checkbox-inner,
  .ant-checkbox-input:focus+.ant-checkbox-inner {
    border-color: green80 !important;
  }

  .ant-checkbox-indeterminate .ant-checkbox-inner::after {
    background-color: green80;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override the [`@checkbox-color`](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less#L228) Less variable.

Answer (score 1):

if this doesn't work

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: #3350ac;
    border-color: #3350ac;
  }
```

then it means it is being overridden but the native ant CSS so put ! important to you CSS
so that it overr

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: #3350ac !important;
    border-color: #3350ac !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all of the above solutions but these solutions do not work for me completely,
sometimes a hover effect in blue color remains or the click effect in blue when we fill the checkbox remains so I changed all classes like this

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: #99b82d !important;
    border-color: #99b82d;
}
.ant-checkbox-wrapper:hover .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: #99b82d !important;
    border-color: #99b82d !important;
}
.ant-checkbox-checked:hover .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: #99b82d !important;
    border-color: #99b82d !important;
}
.ant-checkbox-checked:after {
    border-color: #99b82d !important;
}
.ant-checkbox:hover::after {
    border-color: #99b82d !important;
}
.ant-checkbox:hover .ant-checkbox-inner {
    border-color: #99b82d !important;
}
```

!!! use it with your parent class or it will change all of the checkboxes in your app

if you want to change the color of the inner space of the empty checkbox, then you can use

```
.ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: #e3f0f5 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dude! It works for me in 2023, AntD v.5.10.2

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change Checkbox using only CSS you can also add className to Checkbox and then access it in CSS like this:

```
<Checkbox className="my-checkbox">Your checkbox</Checkbox>
```

And then in CSS

```
.my-checkbox > ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: "red";
    border-color: "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution is using the 'accent-color' property from the [CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#widget-accent):

```css
.ant-checkbox-input {
  accent-color: "green";
}
```

This solution also doesn't have the accessibility issues that many other solutions have.

This can also be used for RadioButtons.

Note that this might not be supported by older browser versions.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69164710/5882233.

Comment: This seems to only work if I don't import the antd css. As soon as I import `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';`, the accent-color is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Talha, it works for me. One more line of code i wanna add is the the color of box when hovering on the label:

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
  background-color: #070707 !important;
  border-color: #070707 !important;
}
.ant-checkbox-wrapper:hover .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
  background-color: #070707 !important;
  border-color: #070707 !important;
}
.ant-checkbox-checked:hover .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
  background-color: #070707 !important;
  border-color: #070707 !important;
}
.ant-checkbox-checked:after {
  border-color: #070707 !important;
}
.ant-checkbox:hover::after {
  border-color: #070707 !important;
}
.ant-checkbox:hover .ant-checkbox-inner {
  border-color: #070707 !important;
}

// ****** I add this one ******
.ant-checkbox-wrapper:hover .ant-checkbox-inner {
  border-color: #070707 !important;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35664396)

Answer (score 0):

You can use config provider:

```
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    token: {
      colorPrimary: "#9A9A9A"
    }
  }}
>
  <Checkbox> check box </Checkbox>
</ConfigProvider>
```