# How to transform background Image on hover in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My intention is to scale my background image when user's mouse enters by 1.5 but my attempts proves abortive. Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Slider from './index';
import horizontalCss from './css/horizontal.scss';
import content from './content';
import SourceView from './SourceView';
import './css/styles.scss';

function Autoplay() {
 return (
  <div>
   
   <Slider classNames={horizontalCss} autoplay={3000}>
    {content.map((item, index) => (
     <div
      key={index}

      style={{ background: `url('${item.image}') no-repeat center center`, 
                           '&:hover': {
       background: 'white',
       transform: 'scale(1.5)',
       }, }}
     >
      <div className="center">
       <div className="textWrapper">
       <h2>{item.title}</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    ))}
   </Slider>
   
  </div>
 );
}

export default Autoplay;
```

What adjustment do I have to do to make this work

Comment: This is not really a React issue, CSS inline styles does not have the option to add pseudo-class effects.  You need to put your effect in a class, and set the `className` of your react component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As people have mentioned earlier, this is not an issue with React; rather, the style property in HTML does not have support for CSS selector like `:hover`. Also do please note that `&:hover` is not valid CSS, but is valid SCSS that is being preprocessed by your webpacker of choice.

However, the hover-specific styles of your `<div>` do not react to anything, so they could be put in a class

```css
.my-image-class {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;

  &:hover {
    background: white;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

And then you could toggle the background-image when not hovering with

```
<div
  key={index}
  className="my-image-class"
  style={{ background: `url('${item.image}') }} 
>
```

---

Bonus: you might think a step further & want to also have you hover image reactive, and this strategy would fall flat. [Kalabasa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998158/11081583) has a great answer that uses dynamic CSS variables ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)) for reactive class properties.

You could state your backgrounds in your class like so:

```css
.my-image-class {
  background-image: var(--my-image);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;

  &:hover {
  background-image: var(--hover-image);
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

And then change the variables dynamically

```
<div
  key={index}
  className="my-image-class"
  style={{ '--my-image': `url(path)`; '--hover-image': `url(other-path)` }} 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline Style doesn't support `pseudo selectors` you need to move your hover style css to your `styles.scss` and try to use a `className` or `id` instead

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ? [Repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-akdwwt?file=style.css)
It scale the block when you hover it.
Here is the code in case Stackblitz does not work:

css :

```
html, body, #app {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.app-component{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
}

.app-component:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition:transform 1s linear;
}
```

app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
    return (
      <div className="app-component">
      </div>
    );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You need to do it in you css, avoid using inline style when you can.